# Flutter : How to get value in Object JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

Good healty everyone, I want to ask something about managing data from JSON. I've JSON format like below :

```
{
"msg": "Success"
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "notelp": "0000000000",
        "user": "no1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "notelp": "1111111111",
        "user": "no2"
    },
],}
```

and I want to get value from variable "notelp", I expect output like this {**"0000000000", "1111111111",**} how to get it ?

I tried this before, but still can't get what I want,

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   final result = json.decode(response.body);
   debugPrint('dataTelp: ${result['data']['notelp']}');
}
```

thank you guys to help me to solve it and stay save.

Comment: did you try to add the 'notelp' to a list? so you get output like ["0000000000", "1111111111",]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can use the forEach or another looping method to get data from a list.*

```
  List outPut = [];
  List data = response['data'];
  data.forEach((element) {
    outPut.add(element['notelp']);
  });
  print(outPut);
```